# Can we apply tag filters to "questions with new activity" in the Questions tab?

Tags: feature-request, new-nav, ignored-tags

If one sits on the questions tab with whatever filter and sorting they have, eventually a message will appear saying *X questions with new activity*. Clicking on this message will add all of these questions to the current list.

[image: Screenshot of X Questions with new activity message]

However, these questions are not filtered by the ignored tags settings. That means that, as far as I can tell, one needs to refresh the page in order to apply this filter.

I'm not even sure if it's a bug or not-so-good design. In any case, can it be made that the ignored tags are checked before showing this message?

Comment: Did you check out what setting (hide/gray out) your ignored tags behaviour is set on the Preferences tab under your profile?

Comment: @kayess I use hide.