# Help set Q&A (TeamDAG) product development priorities

Tags: discussion, new-nav, notifications, question-quality

> [image: Imgur]
>   Thanks everyone for your feedback on this post. As expected, there is a lot of passion around how we spend our resources improving Q&A. There is an undeniable desire to see DAG focus on improvements on the **question quality theme**. As such,  we will be coming back to the community with proposed improvements around this theme and will continue to gathering feedback as we plan, code and ship.
>
> The good news for everyone is that this isn’t a zero sum game. So while question quality is getting special, focused attention, we will still consider improvements across the other themes as well.
>
> Check out the [TeamDAG project update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301449/dag-team-project-updates) post on meta.SE to see what we are currently working on.

You've already been introduced to the [Developer Affinity & Growth team](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351751/meet-team-dag-developer-affinity-growth/) (DAG, yeah go ahead Aussies and make your jokes, but the name really is a [humble nod to this line](https://genius.com/8778041) from Hamilton). The obvious question is, "What the heck is this new team going to do?"

As we’ve reviewed meta feedback we have heard two things loud and clear:

1. Stuff that’s important to the community is not getting done
2. And, we aren't engaging you early enough on the work we are doing

This post is our start at addressing these issues.

We are working hard developing a deep understanding of how everyone from brand new members to our most experienced SO users use Q&A. There are a LOT of suggestions (some big, many small) on how to improve the site. Over 300 [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) posts with +20 or more upvotes have been posted to meta in the last year. And from these insights we are creating a backlog of work that the team is excited about tackling.

But let's be honest, not everyone agrees on where to invest our limited resources. That's where you come in. The purpose of this post is to provide a peek into our backlog so that you all can help collectively prioritize our work.

Based on the analysis of meta posts we have bucketed work into "themes”. Below I’ve briefly described the themes with a [user story](https://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/agile/user-stories) and a list of example investments with related meta posts. Many of you will be familiar with how this goes from your own jobs. The team isn't promising or committing to specific features at this time, but trying to give you a sense of where the investment could lead.

Obviously there are a LOT of other areas where we could invest. We're happy to hear about those as well, but the primary purpose of this post is to ask you to help us prioritize the investment themes below.

So, what do we want from you?

1. Review the themes below
2. If so inclined, write an answer that articulates why we should prioritize one of them over the others
3. Vote for the answers that represent your thinking.

*We would like your feedback by August 9th* so that we can start building features around one of these themes.

So, without further ado…

### Question quality theme

**User story:**  As a first time question asker, I know what is expected of me and can successfully ask a question with a high likelihood of getting a positive response from the community so that I can solve my problem and feel good about my participation in SO.

**Possible investments:**

- [More structured guidance for first time askers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326868/lets-improve-stack-overflows-ask-a-question-page) ([2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324220/should-stack-overflow-be-more-restrictive-about-new-user-registrations), [3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295683/require-new-users-to-check-the-preview-before-posting/295758#295758), [4](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285889/lets-plan-the-second-iteration-of-the-stack-exchange-quality-project))
- [Improved duplicate question discovery/prominence](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261343/give-greater-dominance-placement-to-searching-rather-than-asking-for-new-low-rep) ([2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352450/could-possible-duplicate-of-be-given-prominence-for-answering-users))
- [Better/more prominent inline  help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352028/make-how-to-ask-more-prominent)
- [Mentorship experiment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/353845/stack-overflow-mentorship-research-project)

### Experienced user workflows theme

**User story:** As an SO user, I can find the feature, tool, or content that I need when I need it and SO lets me know when something needs attention within the community so that I can effectively use SO and participate in the community.

**Possible investments:**

- [Address the review icon (top nav) problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350836/please-change-the-review-icon-back-to-a-text-link)
- Question tabs/sub navigation (AKA [whatever happened to New Nav?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308875/new-navigation-release-candidate), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315217/can-we-apply-tag-filters-to-questions-with-new-activity-in-the-questions-tab))
- Other targeted navigation improvements ([1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349204/has-the-top-bar-redesign-met-its-goals), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343653/top-navigation-update) of many posts)

### SO works for me theme

**User story:** As an SO user, the information that is important to me comes to me when and where I want it so that I can proactively engage and participate in the community.

**Possible investments:**

- Improved notifications for email and on-site (again, [many posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/notifications?sort=votes))
- [Responsive design](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344521/request-for-redesign-to-have-better-compatibility-with-1024px-wide-displays)
- Improved favoriting
- Personalized feed based on my favorites

*Note: One theme that we identified and removed from consideration is search. However, we definitely have to work on this in the context of [Channels](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352065/introducing-channels-qa-for-engineering-teams).*

**What comes after voting is done?** Soon after the voting is done we will communicate how your input is impacting our plans and will begin feature level conversations to help define the specific features we will build. And then, most importantly, we will build stuff.

May the best theme <s>win</s> get worked on first.

Comment: Users *come and go*, whether *new or old*. **Quality content** is the anchor and one *is* what one *focuses* on. New users need to get with it. (runs away)

Comment: So we're voting on which bucket/theme we want to see worked first?  Or voting on specific tasks/features within those buckets?

Comment: @ryanyuyu Voting on the theme. The individual features are just examples of what we could work on.

Comment: there was somewhat similar feedback request at MSE: [Let's Plan the Second Iteration of the Stack Exchange Quality Project!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285889/165773) - did you consider picking suggestions from there or it can be assumed to be ignored for DAG purposes?

Comment: @gnat Definitely NOT ignoring the post you linked to. As you can see, most of the feature areas above come directly from meta posts. Happy to have you and others point out others for the team to mine for good ideas.

Comment: I see, thanks. Consider [edit]ing in reference to that post to help other readers see. Another thing I would like to understand better - speaking of "Improved duplicate question discovery/prominence", does this feature request fit under this investment or it should be considered separately: [Could: “Possible duplicate of..” be given prominence for answering users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/352450/839601)

Comment: @Joe I'm still slightly unclear how much resides within the team's remit. Just picking something ottomh - let's say weighting close votes based on badges and possibly extending the gold badge beyond duplicate closure etc... I imagine the amount of "development" work there would be less than the analysis for what impact it would have had, other considerations it may have to the network, maybe do trial runs, etc...I imagine concerns from the CM team is going to sway what actually gets/can get worked on here...

Comment: @gnat I added those links to the relevant parts of the post.

Comment: @JonClements We definitely work closely with the community team on our backlog. They not only set priorities for the community request but have a voice into our overall plan for improvements. Wouldn't have it any other way. As far as the team charter, DAG can work on anything within the context of Q&A as well as site-wide features like sign up/sign in, user messaging and on boarding, and the navigation/chrome. So our scope is fairly broad. The purpose of this post is to narrow that down for the near term.

Comment: [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289364/why-is-duplicate-search-still-awful) is somewhat different than the dupe improvement in the question but I think it complements it.  The dupe search should be more flexible and use synonyms to help the OP find a dupe before they even post a question.

Comment: @NathanOliver That's a good one. I had a search category and had example posts like that one in it. I decided to narrow the choices down to just three and dropped search since I think SO will have to improve there for Channels to succeed. That said, the dupe scenario needs search improvements to really shine.

Comment: The second half of the **question quality theme** user story should be something like: *"If my questions does get downvoted or closed, the best way for me to get answers is by editing my post to fix the problems. Downvotes feel like a tool instead of a peronal attack."* As of now, users have zero incentive to fixing posts instead of just posting more bad questions.

Comment: @KevinWorkman don't forget that there's no way for downvoters to be notified if a question has been fixed up, so even if someone fixes their post, most of the downvotes are bound to stay. I'm sure there's a corresponding feature-request around...but if users complained about seeing _their own_ rep loss, surely they'd revolt if they got notifications about "*this question you downvoted has gone through a major edit*"...

Comment: @AndrasDeak I think that's part of the problem. New users have no incentive to fix their posts because nobody will see it anyway, and experienced users have no incentive to go back and look at old questions because they're almost never updated. Fixing both of these would go a long way towards overall question quality, imho. The point is not to force anybody to do anything, but to make it what they naturally want to do.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Like [this feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311424/follow-up-reminder-option-for-posts)?

Comment: Come on, people! We're programmers, we use Git (or similar), right? The *obvious* meaning for DAG (particularly in all caps like that) is *directed acyclic graph*! Amirite?

Comment: Am I the only one that think that the OP should post a answer for each theme ? Right now, this Q&A has three answers about Question Quality...

Comment: @Rubén I considered that approach but I wanted the community to have more flexibility in giving feedback.

Comment: Does DAG serve only Stack Overflow?  If not, shouldn't this question be on MSE, where lots of highly-committed users who just don't happen to use SO congregate?

Comment: @MonicaCellio Great question. Yes, DAG serves the entire network. In fact, we are currently working on updating the header and footer across the networks (should roll out this month). However, in reviewing the outstanding asks, many of the features and the themes that seem most critical are massive-scale problems that affect SO much more than almost all other sites, so meta.so seemed to be the right location for the post.

Comment: @JoeFriend I agree that MSO is *a* right place to bring these things up. It's just that as a "citizen" of the broader network, I sometimes feel like we don't get a chance to have our input, questions, & concerns heard unless we happen to stumble on posts like this. For example, the new topbar was developed with SO-specific needs in mind, and a lot of us elsewhere on the network have real problems with parts of its design. How do we get those addressed before being given a *fait accompli*? Improving Q&A (like this post) helps all of us; let's find a way to get broad input *too*. Thanks.

Comment: @MonicaCellio, Just FYI: While there was feedback provided on MSO regarding the new top-nav, it was also largely presented as a *fait accompli* to SO (or at least as a "this is happening whether you like it or not"). There were *some* changes made based on the feedback, but it *certainly* wasn't something that was made to fit a requests by users on SO/MSO. The reception of the new top-nav was quite mixed, with several of us developing user scripts to largely change it back to what it used to be (with, perhaps, some of the new features added in).

Comment: Organizing RFEs by what they affect is needed/beneficial, but they should *also* be grouped by their effort required to implement (& expected user experience impact). As it is, some requests have existed for *years* that are very low-effort to improve (e.g. change the *text* descriptions for action buttons in review queues to reflect consensus/audits of how they should be used). Before starting long, difficult projects, take a few days to pick off the low hanging fruit. Developer time is a limited resource, you should first do what provides the best return on investing that limited resource.

Comment: Can we add [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315217/can-we-apply-tag-filters-to-questions-with-new-activity-in-the-questions-tab) to the "SO works for me" theme?

Comment: @user1803551 I added it to the Experienced user workflows theme since it is related to the New Nav.

Comment: @Makyen Totally agree. We will ultimately do some work across these themes when it is low hanging fruit. The goal of this exercise is to figure out where to focus our attention in general. Also, it's important to realize that we want to make changes that have an impact. So we will run experiments and not push things out to the entire site unless they have the impact we are hoping for. That way we don't pile up lots of changes without confirm that they actually address the problem.

Comment: @JoeFriend I'm confused as to how applying the search filter to the list of questions is related to the navigation bar. The behavior hasn't changed with the New Nav.

Comment: Please, add to that list "hire someone who knows CSS".

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286057/6309 would be nice too.

Comment: it'd be nice if network wide changes (a la flagging) were actually announced in a way that ALL sites on the network can see that it's happened, or is happening.  or, y'know, some love got sent to the littler sites every once in a while rather than ONLY focusing on SO.  I know it's the biggest site, but it's not the only one and hasn't been for a VERY long time

Comment: @DForck42 We are definitely working on improvements for the whole network and we consider the needs of all the sites. See my comment above.

Comment: @JoeFriend ok.  it'd be amazing if there was more visibility and communication into what's actually being worked on.  IE a Trello board that y'all use to track where different things are at that we can look at.  One of my biggest gripes as of late is that things either just get ignored, or get plopped on us without any prior notice (e.g. top nav on SO and flagging).  OR, when things get declined there's usually no reason given or a very short reason, no real explanation.

Comment: @DForck42 I hear you loud and clear. The DAG team is working on the right way to do just what you're asking.

Comment: @JoeFriend was discussing with someone in chat.  it'd be awesome if there was a developer blog where big changes were announced that could then be fed into the sidebar like the podcasts

Comment: @DForck42 working on something like that right now. It will be a "new feature/major feature improvement" notification.

Answer (score 194):

**Question Quality**

I feel like a broken record, but it seems so obvious to me.

Specifically, fix the new user question experience to [something like this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/278444/193412). Pre-populating the question box will do several key things:

1. It will tell new users what is expected of them
2. It will help rubber duck basic typo questions (ok, probably a small percentage, but hey, any self help on this regard benefits SO)
3. It will make it clear to the community of users helping them whether the asker even tried to help themselves

Everything you are suggesting, excepting the new question guidance, is a band aid over the real problem: low quality content coming in at a rate which is too high to effectively be dealt with by a bunch of volunteers.

Make the people asking question put in a fraction the effort you are trying to get from the volunteers and things will go much better.

---

How many people who have bug reports internally are presented with a free form text box with literally no prompting?  We have a lot of fields to fill in on our internal bug report tracking -- **because it's useful to the person solving the bug.** Yet on SO, we have an empty box for people to fill in with whatever they want....

Every internal process which remotely resembles SO has some sort of meaningful form to fill out. Hell, even the SE form that we moderators have to use when contacting SE requires more detail than the "ask a question box." And you'd think moderators might be able to do better here than the average SO user...

Comment: I also would vote for question quality because that might be the root cause for the Review problem that is in the Experienced Workflow theme and the review problem is tackled with different community initiatives/chatrooms/bots, like [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570), [SOBotics](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111347), [Charcoal-HQ](https://charcoal-se.org/), [Andy 's Comment flagger](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280546/). So let's fix question quality first to make sure that reviewers aren't swamped with the low quality tsunami.

Comment: If it's going to be the Question theme the winner choice, then picking from the Experienced theme, if we could just have **a text label under each topbar icon**... that wouldn't cost too much extra effort, isn't it?

Comment: FWIW, a [couple of](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260039/could-some-bad-questions-be-avoided-with-additional-prompting) my [requests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266361/the-good-the-bad-the-ugly) to assist with question quality.

Comment: Except SO is *not* a "fix my bug" service in the first place. It's a *knowledge repository*. The suggestion in your meta question seems wholly inappropriate in that light. A good SO question effectively needs to be a good research question, not a bug report. Sometimes, the research question involves fixing a bug, but SO is here to help you *acquire the knowledge necessary to fix the bug*, not just fix it.

Comment: @jpmc26 the qualities which make a good bug report are nearly identical to the qualities that make a good SO question. Clear, reproducible, and with enough information for a reader to actually understand what is going on with the question.

Comment: @enderland Many good SO questions don't even have a behavior to reproduce. Many are simply, ["How do I...?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24006291/1394393) or ["What is...?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25019057/1394393). SO has additional requirements, as well, like being able to determine where the asker is missing information (which itself requires some evaluation of the asker's skill and knowledge level) and ensuring that the question does ask for *too much* information. Your proposal also doesn't discourage typo type questions, which are considered off-topic as well.

Comment: @jpmc26 ... I think it's amusing that the first question you linked as an example of one which "won't fit" already contains all the information requested by the template questions I linked to. And with respect to the second, I would contend a fraction of questions fitting the "what is..?" criteria are actually good fits for SO in the first place.

Comment: @enderland It does not contain, "What happens when you run the code?" It doesn't even expand on what happens when they run the things they tried. Nor does it even really make a lot of sense to do so. In the strictest sense, it doesn't even contain code "showing your problem," as there isn't a problem to show. The only thing it really contains is the desired result and some sample input (which your prompts don't even ask for), and it's still a good question.

Comment: @jpmc26 In my experience the “what is X” type questions tend to be very broad and frequently unclear. But you bring up a good point: a single question template won't fit all questions. I could imagine that a drop-down list of different templates for main on-topic areas could be helpful, or that high-level guidance might also work. Since we require users to do some research first, literally every good on-topic question is going to fit a schema like “*{How can I do/What is} $x? I {did/understand} $y but that is wrong because $reasons.*”

Comment: @amon I think your suggestion is a much better starting point than the very "bug report" centric wording in the linked question. I don't really have a problem with *some* kind of template/suggestion in principle, but the wording there seems to give all the wrong impressions about how SO should be used.

Comment: I'm one of the swamped flaggers, but what is also to consider is the first time users, allowing them to ask crappy question, you bet they do not feel that SO is a great place to be. It's just unfair to all of us even first time users, when I was still fresh on SO, I posted [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316681/lets-give-the-original-poster-a-chance-to-post-an-appropriate-question), not the best meta post, but that's what I think first user experience is.

Comment: Another vote for something closer to what amon suggests than the linked question, in terms of templates. Take a look at the [highest voted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes) SO questions, and (even ignoring all the "how do I do X in git?") most of them are *not* about debugging a single error or piece of code.

Comment: @mbrig I don't really see what side you're arguing for, but the only thing that list of highly-voted questions proves is that _"debug this code for me"_ aren't popular questions. They're the most frequently asked kind of question though, and that kind of question could greatly benefit from a template.

Comment: @CodeCaster I think mbrig's point is that while the template in the link might help the most common kind of question, it risks actively discouraging *good* questions that don't fit it.

Comment: @jpmc26 It's a bit disappointing but I think the "knowledge repository" aspect of SO isn't as much of a priority as it used to be.

Answer (score 106):

I agree with [enderland's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/354127/189134)  and more so with [rene's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354125/help-set-dag-product-development-priorities#comment498924_354127): **Question quality first**

Reviews are a downstream effect of poor question quality. If we can improve question quality (and duplicate detection), I think the number of review tasks will change dramatically.

Question quality is cited by higher rep users as a leading cause for their disengagement. This [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow) alone has 50+ answers. [Here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324243/the-life-of-answering-questions-on-stack-overflow) is another talking about how to handle the quality issue. Helping users ask better questions should be the priority. Discouraging poor questions should also be a priority.

Improving question quality will help those experienced users find questions they want to answer. I think it will also help with the review problems.

Comment: This is the only correct answer. Sure, the review queues are a problem, but they're really a problem _caused by_ another problem. Work on the cause, and the secondary problem becomes smaller.

Answer (score 33):

**Question quality**

Why? Because it's the primary factor deciding about the usefulness of SO and - as has already been mentioned by others - improving question quality will have a lot of positive secondary effects (e.g. on the review queues).

**Regarding the proposals**

- *More structured guidance for first time askers (2, 3, 4)* Definitely. Let's try the wizard-style approach (targeted at new users) or the pre-filled question area (which might make sense for everyone, not just new users) - perhaps with some A/B testing to compare both approaches?
- *Improved duplicate question discovery/prominence (2)* Might help, I'm not sure about this.
- *Better/more prominent inline help* Yes, please. Perhaps we could even add a simple multiple-choice quiz on the sign-up page to ensure new users have read the text before clicking "I agree", but this might be too unfriendly to new users.
- *Mentorship experiment* I'm not a big fan of this, as it might worsen the existing help vampire problem.

If I had to choose a single proposal, I'd go for *More structured guidance for first time askers* without a second thought. This could be tremendously useful.

Answer (score 32):

## Improve Search

The current Stack Overflow search algorithm often misses useful content in its search results. When I want to find something I usually have to use Google, but it is a pain typing in `site:stackoverflow.com`. It would be much more convenient to have the SO search function work better.

This would help out all three of the themes you listed above. It would improve question quality by reducing the number of duplicate questions. It would allow experienced users to find a tool or resource just by typing a word or two. And it would help everyone to find the information they need more quickly.

I'm just getting started in my study of Artificial Intelligence and Deep Learning, but it seems like there is an application for that here. Even "simple" keyword search improvements would help, though. I'm sure this is not an easy task, but I think it would be worth the investment of your limited resources.

Comment: Aside: I use a [userscript](https://github.com/normalhuman/CustomSE/blob/master/GoogleSearch.user.js) that invokes Google search with that parameter when one presses Alt-Enter in the SE search box. A sort of thing that could be built-in...  I'm not sure internal search can ever match a popular search engine that uses a lot of traffic data to judge how  useful content is (not only how well it matches the query).

Comment: Just as an aside, we are working on improving search as a part of our work on [Channels](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/352082/7317251).

Comment: Not just the search algorithms ... results display also. Given a whole series of results there really isn't enough detail most of the time to find better quality matches without flipping through lots of links

Comment: While this would certainly be nice to have, I don't think it should be top priority. Implementing a search engine similar to Google will require quite a bit of effort. I think resources would be better spent elsewhere.

Comment: @Lundin Strongly disagree. The more people can find existing questions that resolve their issues, the less garbage we'll all have to sift through. =) If Google level quality is desired, I'd say find a way to integrate an actual Google search mechanism.

Comment: @jpmc26 But I have a Google search field in my web browser... so for me as a user it is just a matter which search field to click on: the one on SO or the one in the browser. It is not productive to demand that SO should launch a huge project just so that those two search boxes I see on my screen both give good results, instead of just one. I can just learn to click on the Google one. What this really boils down to is that SO has spent tons of resources on completely useless projects over the past 2-3 years, projects that added absolutely nothing to the site or user experience.

Comment: @Lundin Improving the search is about preventing people from asking duplicates. That's an improvement for the user asking, but it's a bigger improvement for those of us answering. It's a way of improving question quality. Yes, some users who don't care will ignore it and ask anyway, but a reduction still helps.

Comment: Also the filtering - many years have passed and we still can't search inside our favourite questions and answers which makes the fav button useless

Answer (score 24):

### Question Quality Theme, but including answerer experience

TL;DR: The Question Quality User Story starts from the POV of a new user, but the people who have a problem with question quality are the expert answerers. You also seem to assume bad quality askers are mostly new and/or benevolent. If this theme focuses solely on the new/LQ user experience without thinking of the answerer experience it will probably miss the point.

---

I think that the DAG team should focus on question quality, but start by reevaluating their POV. When I read this:

> User story: As a first time question asker, I know what is expected of me and can successfully ask a question with a high likelihood of getting a positive response from the community so that I can solve my problem and feel good about my participation in SO.

I can't help but think that your view of the question quality problem is inherently flawed. This user story nicely describes the vision you have, but *it assumes some form of cooperation and benevolence from the user*. While it's true that some of the first time askers on SO are receptive to guidance and feedback, or even ask themselves questions such as "what is expected from me" or "is my question on topic for this site", I don't believe they are the root of the problem. From my perspective, the problem is that the user story for a significant amount of low quality askers currently looks more like this:

> User Story: As a question asker, I want my problem solved with minimal effort. I do not have to care about question quality, topicality, or the goals of SO. I can just ignore and/or complain about people who want to enforce the site standards and there are enough answerers who will help me anyway. I don't care about question bans either as this account contains nothing of value and throwaways are cheap.

Imagine a user who says "screw your site and community, I just want my problem (or homework) solved, preferably yesterday" - how would your current story even begin to apply to somebody like this? In my opinion, that story completely misses the point. The LQ askers are usually not the ones who complain about not being able to solve their problems, because unless their question is deleted in less time than it takes for somebody to write any answer then even many of the crappiest questions will be answered by someone (be it for rep farming or out of a misguided desire to help; in my experience this applies even to unanswerable questions where users try polishing turds instead of down/close-voting).

The reason why we are having a discussion about question quality is because many of the *answerers are the ones unhappy with the current situation*. So while I do think that question quality is the most important theme by far, I think it should also include a user story from the answerer POV, e.g. like this:

> User Story: As an expert answerer, I want to see new, unanswered questions for my favorite tags which are worth my time instead of crap written by people who barely manage to type coherently. If I do stumble upon the rare question which does not meet SO's very high quality standards, I do have moderation tools available which have a meaningful impact on the visibility and/or deletion of the question and which cannot be easily countered by people who don't care about site quality.

Of course, that user story might be way harder to solve (I'm not even sure if it is solvable). It also might not be possible to align with the goals of SE who seem to prioritize volume over quality. But the only meaningful way to stop people complaining about question quality is to fix the problem for the answerers. If you focus on "new asker" experience, you might not reach the existing users who produce a steady stream of crap only slightly decent enough to not get them question banned. And if you do include them, I'm not sure if it will lead to meaningful changes in their behaviour. Maybe it would turn out to be another attempt at turd polishing, just on another level and scale.

On the other hand, I do not think any answerer actually cares about the amount of crap questions on the site; only about the amount that they have to sift through to find good questions to answer (and of course, about the quality of SO results they get from Google Search when attempting to solve their own problems). So if you had working solutions for answerers to filter the crap nobody would complain about question quality.

---

Personally, all of this does not even matter that much to me, because I'm not actively participating on SO any more. I still get here from Google Search, and often read the hot meta topics, but I've stopped answering a long time ago (and the very few questions I asked usually didn't get answered or even got much feedback, maybe because they are harder than the usual drivel - or I just suck at asking). I did get demotivated by seeing a deluge of bad questions and answers, uncountable duplicates, and worst of all too many users who did not care about any of this (a lot of askers who ignored feedback or got angry, and even more others who instead of downvoting/closing questions happily upvoted/edited/reopened everything that wasn't pure spam because "they tried, so let's be nice to them").

I've just checked my front page again and it still shows me mostly crap, and still most of it is not closed and downvoted, but answered instead. Call me elitist or whatever, but I'm hoping for an SO fork/clone which focuses on professionals and has ridiculous quality standards - e.g. if your question can be answered by copypasting its title into Google Search, that's an instaban.

Comment: I think it would be more accurate to say that it's not really DAG team vision but [that of Spolsky](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296166/839601). And it really looks slippery that they have picked to follow it because it seems to be fundamentally broken, "how come that after years of plugging users' mouths and twisting their arms with _summers of love_ and _hunting the snark_, the second-highest-voted question at MSO is [Why is Stack Overflow so **negative** of late?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251758/839601) Makes one wonder if this way works, doesn't it?"

Comment: For someone who's "not actively participating", you've certainly managed a [Mr. Miyagi-like level of hitting the nail](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lMgEXVOmvgI) on the head. _(warning: YouTube link)_ Unfortunately, [I'm pretty sure](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/351792/) the only non-deaf ears it will fall on are those of the choir.

Comment: "I do not think any answerer actually cares about the amount of crap questions on the site" -- well, no, I did sign up for the whole "make a repository of good Q&A" thing described as the Atwood way in gnat's link, or over here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255019/

Comment: @Frank, of course, so did I. But in practice, would you care about crap questions if they were not easily discoverable, auto-roombaed after a while, and you would not stumble upon them organically (by browsing the site) or by googling? They would not have much of an an impact on the site except for using a bit of storage space.

Comment: Great answer. I also have generally found that if I have a really good question it won't get answered. It will barely even get viewed.

Answer (score 23):

**Experienced user workflow theme**

## Better (mortal) moderation tools

There's been a few requests over the years for some [improvements to the 10k tools](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345140/enhance-the-delete-list-of-the-moderator-tools). The pages are basic and confusing.

In this same vein, [New Answers to Old Questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312246/make-the-new-answers-to-old-questions-real-time) (colloquially known as NATO) is also a basic page that needs some love. NATO is a major way we find bad answers and flag them for moderation/queues but it's clunky.

## Scaling close votes

[Originally proposed on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281818/is-using-reputation-to-scale-the-number-of-close-votes-the-best-way), the conversation died on the vine. Let's be honest: this really is a SO thing (I have close privs on some other SE sites and rarely use them). The Close Queue is perpetually 10k, but everyone gets only 50 votes. There are plenty of users who rarely use their votes, while there are [some who would easily use more if given them](https://stackoverflow.com/users/578411/rene?tab=activity). Scaling votes would help the community and active non-moderator users.

Comment: Don't forget where the number of votes was increased and despite the initial enthusiasm and uptake, only a couple of people reached the new maximum and then not consistently during the trial period. People burn out. We need *more people* reviewing - not the same users *reviewing more*.

Comment: @JonClements I think we need both more reviewers and higher CV limit. Experiment you mention has proven only that giving over 40-50 _reviews_ is a dead end, this is not really related to CV limit if you think of it. User who completed their 40 reviews should be able to get back to normal browsing of tags they are active at and cast CVs normally, without frustrating choice of how to spread 10 remaining votes. This is especially true for silver / gold tag badge holders who are by definition active in their tags

Comment: @jonclements I'm more arguing for CVs to work more like flags. Give 2k users 10 flags and scale to 100. Would give more CVs to avid users *and* let more people review

Comment: I'd rather have more effective votes than simply more votes.

Comment: 2 votes only to close, or to leave open, or to re-open.

Comment: Note: *many* sites have problems with their CV queue once they reach a certain point of maturity. Android Enthusiasts, ELU, Drupal, etc, etc, etc. So CV scaling is anything but an SO-only problem.

Comment: @JonClements, As Cœur mentioned, in addition to increasing the number of close votes (let qualified people who want help make SO better do so), the other thing is to reduce the number of close-/reopen-votes needed to close/reopen a question (Q). While I think 2 CV is too low, 3 seems to be good. The point of close/reopen is that a Q is closed *quickly* to prevent answers being added to off-topic Qs. The OP then can edit the Q to make it on-topic & have it reopened. There are multiple other issues involved (e.g. first edit auto-entry into the reopen queue when it's not an edit by the OP, etc.).

Comment: @JonClements I think the first priority regarding reviews needs to be to get the audit situation cleared up. Audits need a complete rework.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345134/the-10k-tools-could-do-with-some-love

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345140/enhance-the-delete-list-of-the-moderator-tools

Comment: This answer was the only place I found the meaning to NATO from searching Google, SO and MSO...

Answer (score 12):

**Improved duplicate question discovery/prominence**

I vote for this. Generally people search on Google, find apt question on Stack and bumps to that question. But what if Google does not show search result of Stack which is already dealt with very well on SO? (I have experienced this myself) Let (new) users come on Stack Overflow site instead and allow them to search the query they are looking for. If they gets their query resolved from search results, not only will it reduce duplication of questions but also give an all round good first appearance of SO to them.

Currently the search boxes on header on stack don't even show up suggestions or autofilters. Obviously we get tons of similar question while we attempt to ask question. But that's seem not enough.

Comment: I agree that this is important. Alternatively, some manner of working FAQ system where the contents of the FAQ can be user moderated rather than automatically generated (as is the case with the "featured" tab). Currently all the major (language) tags have implemented some manner of custom FAQ system, and most of them have done so in completely different ways.

Answer (score 7):

**Question Quality**

SO is very unfriendly to new users.  Often they ask a question that through honest ignorance does not fulfill SO guidelines--heck I do that and I've a 1000+ rep!

I suggest the following steps:

- **Make question help more prominent.** Yes, for new users, a preview question dialog which outlines the basic question guidelines would be helpful.  It would also be helpful for users who get downflagged frequently.
- **Make question help smart.**  You have an enormous amount of data on questions and flagging.  Use it to construct a machine-learning smart question help dialog.  When a question appears to violate SO guidelines, put up a feature-relevant preview dialog addressing the guideline violation.

Comment: +1 yes to making question help smart!

Answer (score 5):

**Stuff that’s important to the community is not getting done**

*we’ve reviewed meta feedback* - just get on with that for the time being. Specifically, fix what does not work (or explain why not) before taking on a lot of new development.

See: [What percent of Meta feature requests are read or seriously considered?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354713/what-percent-of-meta-feature-requests-are-read-or-seriously-considered?cb=1)

Answer (score 4):

A way to explain to someone why their question is a duplicate and if they then accept that the duplicate provides the answer, reward the person who found the duplicate with +15 rep.

Documentation was meant to solve this problem by allowing one example to be used to answer many related but not identical questions - this requirement has not gone away.

We now have the concept of canonical questions that cover common problems and are often used as a target when voting to close as duplicate.  But often the person who asked the question is missing a few insights needed to understand they are having the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

I see a lot of posts about question quality.

As a relatively new user, I think I come from a different viewpoint than many others.

While I think pre-populating the question box is helpful, I feel like most people learn from watching it done right.

If there was a link to a list of canonical "good questions", I think new users would be able to look at that and write much better, much faster.

It's like learning a new writing style or imitating an author; we need more examples that are clear and diverse.

Comment: Pick your favourite tag, then click the "frequent" tab and you'll get a list of questions that are very likely good ones.

Answer (score 0):

### SO Works for Me!

In this I'll take the dark horse and champion the "SO Works for Me" mantra.  I consider myself to be a power user, and I would love to see some of these features implemented:

- Proper web worker notifications; the system [that I have in place](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/302606/1079354) has almost driven me to buy an AWS Lambda instance and do it myself
- Responsive design; while this has the potential to cannibalize the mobile app(s), I feel like responsive design in this arena would supersede this, given that most power functionality *isn't* in the mobile app
- Favoriting improvements; it'd be nice to really use favorites in a more meaningful and impactful way in my daily usage, as opposed to the informal and horribly ad-hoc way of keeping track of canonical duplicates (hey, that'd be a useful thing too!)
- A personalized feed would be nifty too, given that I like to see what I like to see, and this *might* help users find questions that they actually *want* to engage with, too.

Comment: Responsive design? But... tables...

Comment: @canon:  Tables are *so* modern email, though.

Comment: What exactly are you thinking of when you say "a personalized feed"? I already use the home page ("interesting" questions) as a personalized feed, and it works extremely well. The system knows exactly which types of questions I like to answer (based upon tags) and automatically selects a view of the most recent questions with those tags. I usually find a large number of them "interesting", and all it takes is a refresh to get a new batch once I grow uninterested in the previous batch. Combine this with tag searches for more questions and more depth, and that's a sufficient workflow for me.

Comment: @CodyGray:  I would imagine an evolution of what we currently have.  We have had dozens of suggestions floating around prior to help improve the kinds of questions we see; I can only presume that this is their intent behind this bullet point.

Comment: @Makoto Exactly. Also, you have to play around with the system quite a bit to find out all the bells and whistles. I think we can make the individual components work better and make them better together as well. A lot of members don't even know about all the things you can do to help personalize your experience.

Comment: If this is the direction they take first, we should change the team title to "**D**eck chair re**A**rrangement **G**roup".

Comment: @JoshCaswell:  Harsh.  At a minimum we'd be able to see some nice QoL features with this, whereas things like question quality and improvement, while *vital*, feels like an NP-Complete problem.  I talk at length about moving goalposts in a few of my recent answers/comments; you may peruse them at your leisure.  This is why I'm slightly more keen to see the QoL work go in *before* the team tackles the really complicated work.

Comment: @CodyGray When I go to Questions > Home I get questions with tags I've never heard of and no questions similar to what I like to answer. How is it working for you?

Comment: Sorry, but I just can't get that excited about a new plasma screen and DVR when the only thing on is _The Land Before Time XVII_ and the television room floor is flooded. (Really liked your Meta question about Python questions; it's something about the tag I've often wondered myself.)

Comment: I don't know what "Questions > Home" is, @user1803551. I don't see that anywhere. The page you want is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting), which is the same thing you get when you navigate directly to https://stackoverflow.com/.

Comment: @CodyGray That's the one. Currently only 2/15 related questions. Looks pretty random.

Comment: Maybe you have to have "favorite tags" set up in order for it to work effectively? @user1803551

Comment: @CodyGray I have these tags set for years already. [Here](http://imgur.com/a/CjJyT) is an example of what I get. I add and remove some favorite tags sometimes, doubt it changes anything.

Comment: You had my upvote at "Responsive design." That's pretty much where I stopped reading.

Answer (score -11):

## Editing posts on SO doesn't work for newbies or experienced users.

1. The rep system appears to provide little to no value, is easily gamed, sets up a largely arbitrary pecking order that creates unnecessary drama, and provides perverse incentives. For example, it provides greater rewards to users who write lots of quick answers to simple questions (even ones that Google can already answer for you) than to users who write more time-consuming answers to harder questions.
2. There's no allowance for mass automated edits, so people get blamed, harassed and even edit-banned for fixing typos. On Wikipedia, bots are valuable and valued members of the community. Do something about that.
3. The excuses for not allowing minor constructive edits is they bump posts (fixable, put limits on the number of bumped, as opposed to new, posts on front pages), that they fill the review queue (fixable, have a way to mass review mass edits) and that basically only people with 2000 rep should be allowed to make minor edits (see #1).
4. SO's community is unreasonably hostile towards newbies and people who want to nibble around the edge of questions and answers to improve them, but who don't have the time or inclination to spend half an hour to multiple hours fixing everything that's wrong with a question or answer. Work on getting the community to stop hating.

Comment: The "stop the hate" line just made me remember that a few years i got disgusted by SO for being thrown away, because I didn't know how to properly ask a question ... and just 10mn ago i downvoted a post without explaining why (it was an XY poorly written) ... *flies off to fix that*

Answer (score -22):

Some people will hate this.....

As someone who has made the effort to get a 1st class degree in CompSci, I do not wish to see questions from users who have not got a degree (2:1 or above) in CompSci, or have proven their ability by writing quality answers.

It is a long time since I have answered many questions on SO as they are just so depressing, mostly from people who are not willing to buy a book and read it.

So let me **choose** to filter the front page based on the verified qualifications of the person asking the question.

Comment: Not sure what "2:1" means. https://cs.stackexchange.com/tour seems like a better fit for what you're talking about, since programming != CS.

Comment: As I understand it, a lot of undergrad "CompSci" degrees are actually _Programming as a Job_ degrees (or treated that way by their recipients). I think the distinction is more about having a certain amount of experience just thinking about this stuff, as opposed to waking up one day and saying "I'm going to make the next Flappy Bird!"

Comment: @JoshCaswell Interestingly, my BS in Information and Computer Science from UC Irvine was pretty much the opposite: lots of CS, essentially no instruction in how to program.  Most of my cohort would have a hard time just getting to an interesting programming problem, much less turning it into an interesting question.

Comment: When I was first starting out in my career, I worked directly underneath a man who didn't have a CS degree and he could outengineer me *blind*.  It was truly amazing to watch and witness, and he didn't have (or really need) the extra paperwork.  I have a CS degree and five years later, I feel like I'm at least *close*.   By not allowing someone to post based on some piece of paper, you cut out ***a lot of intelligent users*** for absolutely no gain.  You also don't know how to deal with liars; someone could lie about their highest education level just to get past that filter...

Comment: Requiring a CS degree would completely exclude all of my contributions. Not sure if that would bother you or not, but just something to think about.

Comment: That could be easy to fake aniway, I don't see SE staff running after every university in the world to check that. Furthermore in computering, there is even more a lot of self taught people here than in others fields. And quite some of them are among the best. If we remove the CS Degree and keep the idea, you want to only see question/answer from people that have high rep of a high voted answers ? You just need to answers a HNQ question for that.