# How can new questions get more eyeballs on them?

Tags: discussion

Go to page 2 of Questions for Stack Overflow. You'll see a lot of recent questions, mostly asked between 5 and 10 minutes ago, and mostly with 3 views each. Go to page 13 (approximately one-hour old questions at the time of writing). There are still lots of questions with single-digit views.

There are obviously lots of people using Stack Overflow, but what proportion of questions are relevant to them?

When I scan down the list of tags on a single page, only a few are in my domain of expertise, and some are outside of my domain of interest. There are very few that I could actually answer.

Is Stack Overflow too generic?

It seems that people mostly look at questions on page 1, but these questions don't stay on page 1 for more than a few minutes because so many new questions are being asked.

Maybe this is not even a problem and is a good thing! Is there a way to show more relevant questions by default to people who could answer them or is this not a problem?

Comment: Are you using the [new nav](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308875/new-navigation-release-candidate)?

Comment: Also, your title sounds like you're trying to get more views on questions but the question at the end sounds like you're looking for things to answer. Did you mean to ask both questions or just the last one?

Comment: @BSMP I don't have much time to answer questions. It just seems that a lot a questions can potentially disappear into a black hole before the right people can come along and answer them. If I'm looking for an answer, I'll search the questions for my current problem. So, three reasons to visit, ask a question, answer a question, find someone else's answer that works for you. I'm wondering if there's an issue with new questions getting answered that it's a matter of luck whether an expert happens to be viewing the 1st page within 5 minutes of a question being asked.

Comment: @BSMP Is the new nav where everything is backwards and really confusing when you switch sites because nothing is in the same place? If yes, then yes I am.

Comment: Anyone looking for relevant questions to answer can filter the list with tags. The new nav even allows you to create tabs based on tags. So even if you're looking at the newest questions they aren't coming in as fast because you're only looking at ones that match your filter.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, looking at "newest" questions is a bit like trying to drink water from a firehose. It doesn't work out very well. Too many new questions are posted every second, pushing out the previous ones before they ever get eyeballs on them. You quickly lose track of where you were, and can easily miss the signal amongst all the noise.

[image: A dog trying to drink water from a fire hydrant]
<sup>(Image from ["6 reasons why your business needs to curate content and 17 practical tips for doing it"](http://jaypalter.ca/2013/09/6-reasons-why-your-business-needs-to-curate-great-content-and-17-practical-tips-for-doing-it/),  by Jay Palter.)</sup>

However, it turns out that very few <strike>programmers</strike> people are experts in everything. Instead, we are all experts in a fairly narrow subset of topics, where we would prefer to focus our attention. That means the "newest" questions page is essentially useless, because it shows an unfiltered view of *all* questions coming in, including many that we don't care about.

It works better to drink water from a glass or jug. Stack Overflow has many types of drinking vessels available, but all of them rely on tags. We use tags here to categorize content, and these are the *primary* means by which experts are connected with relevant questions. If you're an expert in Java, you follow the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag. There are many ways that you can use tags to find questions to answer.

1. **Tag searches.**  One of the simplest ways to find questions by tag is simply to search/filter by tag. You can type a tag into the search box at the top of every page, and it will display the newest questions *with that tag*. You can also use more advanced operators, allowing you to combine tags, exclude tags, and so on. I have a couple of these search queries bookmarked, and this is what I principally work from when answering questions. In my conversations with other experienced users, I find that I'm far from alone.
2. **Favorite/ignored tags.** Sometimes, though, even a tag search turns up too many false positives and noise. Consider that you're a *desktop* Java programmer trying to follow the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag. You will quickly be overwhelmed with [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) questions. You could filter these out of your search, but if you *never* wanted to see any Android questions, you could add the [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) tag to your list of "ignored tags" (tracked and stored with your profile) so that these questions are *always* filtered out (or simply appear greyed-out, as you prefer). Similarly, you can add tags to your "favorites" list, and questions with these tags will be shown highlighted (light orange background) in lists of questions, making them easier to spot. I make *extensive* use of favorite/ignored tags. It really didn't take me long to get them set up, and I've gradually refined the list over the years, so that by now, the number of irrelevant questions that I see is manageable.
3. **"Interesting" questions.** The Stack Overflow home page is actually one of the most underrated views that exists on this site. This shows you questions that the site deems ["interesting" for you](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting). Such calculation is based on your favorite/ignored tags, as well as algorithmically determined based on the tags of the questions you tend to interact with, as well as [several other factors](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/09/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/). [This page shows which tags the system thinks are most interesting to you](https://stackoverflow.com/users/tag-future/366904); it's creepy how accurate it is, at least for me. So, this type of "interesting" filtering actually happens by default, just by interacting with the site, even if you haven't taken the time to customize your tag preferences. I camp out on the home page most of the time, and *always* use that view when I'm away from my primary machine (and thus my custom tag search queries are unavailable).

Using these tools, you can get a pretty nice, filtered view of questions that *should* be interesting and relevant to you. By using tags effectively, a number of smaller, more focused "communities" can exist within the larger site that is Stack Overflow. I'm of the opinion that this works far better than if we were to break up the site into a number of smaller, more dedicated sites, because we can essentially have the best of both worlds.

Notice, though, that I've emphasized the word "should". Why? Because there are still a lot of low-quality, off-topic, garbage questions that get asked *within* your domain of interest. For example, I follow the [x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x86) tag because I'm an expert in assembly language and micro-optimization for that architecture. Unfortunately, that tag attracts a lot of, "What computer should I build?" and "My computer is broken?" questions. In language tags, there are a dizzying array of no-effort code dumps and assignments *sans* questions. These, as you say, push out the interesting and relevant questions.

I think this is one of the biggest problems facing Stack Overflow today. And it affects everyone equally. It affects askers of good questions, because it means their questions don't get seen and therefore they don't get the answers they deserve. It affects answers, because it means they drown in noise, waste a lot of time, and can't find the questions they're actually here to answer because they enjoy doing it. It even affects the people who navigate to Stack Overflow from search engines, because the relevant questions they've found are less likely to have a good answer.

And yet, I'm not sure what can be done about it. Sure, I have a few ideas, like expanding the close-vote privileges given to gold tag badge holders, tightening up the quality filters, and [improving the user experience surrounding the Ask Question page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326868/lets-improve-stack-overflows-ask-a-question-page). Some of these (like the latter) are in various stages of being implemented. Others are possibly on the company's radar, but low priority. Still others haven't even been seriously considered yet.

The good news, though, is that [Stack Overflow has finally created a team dedicated to improving Q&A, and they are soliciting feedback from us](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354125/help-set-qa-teamdag-product-development-priorities). If you have ideas on how the site can be improved—especially with regard to allowing users to find questions and/or decreasing the amount of low-quality questions—then please share them!

Comment: That x86 tag problem is a bit of a doozy, if you'd turn it into x86-assembly in an attempt to make it less ambiguous you'd still get questions about building/assembling computers.

Comment: I just noticed that the front page (which I almost never visit) and "Questions" which I end up on quite a bit are almost identical, except that I get "Interesting" vs "Newest" questions. Maybe "Interesting" could be added to the "Questions" page?